# how i can concatenate two variable it type Text Field?

Tags: ios, swift

how i can concatenate two variable it type Text Field?

```
@IBOutlet weak var answerScreen: UILabel!
// The first number
@IBOutlet weak var valueOne: UITextField!
// The second number
@IBOutlet weak var valueTwo: UITextField!
```

Comment: what do you mean. Tell your input and output?

Comment: i need  inside answerscreen concatenation valueone and two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get what you want. Is this what you want to achieve?

```
answerScreen.text = valueOne.text! + valueTwo.text!
```

> String values can be added together (or concatenated) with the addition operator (+) to create a new String value:

Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID291) for more details

Comment: another case: `answerScreen.text = "\(valueOne.text!)\(valueTwo.text!)"`

Comment: @dimpiax Why to complicate things as it is a string and can be achieved just by '+' operator. Your solution can be handy if the user has other values to be concatenated than String

Comment: i know but  i told about uitextfield not string !

Comment: Still couldn't get you, Explain properly

Answer (score 0):

At first your question is not clear and as per the comments above it is still confusing what you want to do. What do you want do with concatenating two `textFields`? Moreover it is not possible to concatenate two `UITextField` objects. We assume that you want to concatenate the `values` of these 2 `textFields` which can be done as shown in the @Rajan's answer above and also with my answer below:

```
guard let value1 = valueOne.text else { return }
guard let value2 = valueTwo.text else { return }
answerScreen.text = value1 + value2
```